# post array in Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

How to post an array using Alamofire. Alamofire request takes only Dictionary type as a parameter: `[String : Any]`.

But I want to pass an array as a parameter, not Dictionary.

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: [String : Any], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:])
```

Is there any way to solve it ..?

Comment: you can add array inside of dictionary ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var request = URLRequest(url: try! "your api".asURL())
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let arrParam = ["abc", "xyz"]
request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: arrParam)
Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { response in
    switch (response.result) {
    case .success:
        //success code here
    case .failure(let error):
        //failure code here
    }
}
```